# How to show multiple value in jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to design a multi-column select/search box as the one shown below.

[image]

I thought about using jQuery-UI Autocomplete widget. I will make the list appear in focus so the user can select directly from the list or start typing in the search box to filter the data shown.

I know I can feed the Autocomplete an array of objects as the source and decide a label to be shown as the selected item when the user selects a row.

What I want is to show more than two columns on the list. Any idea how to accomplish that?

thanks,

Comment: Look at http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem

Answer (score 0):

Use [autocomplete renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) to customize your search results. For multiple column view, use html code in rendering to render table like view. And then use [this](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions) library to render html in autocomplete UI.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't give me what I want. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using  [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) from twitter.

Paired with the bloodhound engine it gives the ability to specify costume templates for the list.